# Loop repeated do statement with mouse left button variable click & hold

Tags: c++, winapi

*Hey, currently testing a autoclicker for a few games, I am quite new to C++*

How can I use left mouse button to run a do statement for the mouse click function without it stopping the do statement

I've tried different flags including :

```
input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
```

with mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF)

```
do {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80000000) {
        enabled = true;

        while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80000000) {
            Sleep(1000 / cps);
            INPUT input;
            input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input.mi.dx = 0;
            input.mi.dy = 0;
            input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
            input.mi.mouseData = 0;
            input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
            input.mi.time = 0;
            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        }
    }


} while (true);
```

I am trying to make it so when you hold down left click, it runs the while statement containing the autoclicking function, without stopping the while statement due to repetitive clicking.

Comment: Never mind hooking this up to input, your call to SendInput is no good and won't work on its own. Debug code by making sure the constituent parts work. Do that first.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you should notice in your code:

First, How to judge the return value of [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you
>   should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the
>   Remarks.

the type of return value is SHORT which is 2 bytes. So try `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000` instead.

Second, How to use `SendInput()` to send different mouse state.
You should create a new `INPUT` data to save different action, but not just combine all of them.

Code Sample:

```
do {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000)
        {
            enabled = true;
            while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000) 
            {
                INPUT input[2];
                input[0].type = input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                input[0].mi.dx = 0;
                input[0].mi.dy = 0;
                input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
                input[1].mi.dx = 0;
                input[1].mi.dy = 0;
                input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
                SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT) * 2);
            }
        }


    } while (true);
```